# Why not ‘mark’ instead of ‘marked’?

Tags: word-usage

> The success of the battle marked the turning point in the civil war.

In this sentence, why not use ‘mark’ instead of ‘marked’?

I think it should use ‘mark’ because this thing is a objective thing. It marked/marks/will mark the turning point.

Comment: Can you tell us where this sentence came from? (See [Why you should cite your source](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source) on meta.)

Comment: @J.R. Page 337, last line, ISBN: 9787560056326

Comment: Don’t tell me, tell the community

Comment: What do you mean by "objective thing"? *The success of the battle* can be replaced by *it*, and you can't say *it mark* – it's always *it marks* (in the present).

Comment: The ISBN appears to belong to a Chinese book of English vocabulary exercises, is that right?  If so, more context is unlikely!

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Why should the objectvity of the thing affect the form of the verb?

Comment: @AntonSherwood Yes.

Comment: @AntonSherwood Okay, now I know I was wrong before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The success of the battle marks the turning point in the civil war.

[the civil war is not yet over. The time is the present.]

The includes the use of the present tense as historical present. Historical present is merely using the present tense for the past tense (given in sentence two below) and is used in some history and literary contexts.

The success of the battle marked the turning point in the civil war.

[the civil war is finished. The time is the past.]

Comment: +1, I agree except for the historical present in which present can be used without having the meaning you mentioned.

Comment: Turning points tend to be decided or identified after the event, and thus are generally in the past.

Comment: Battles are only a "success" for one side, aren't they?

Comment: @LucianSava From the point of the storyteller, the time is the present, or rather, the situation is described as if it were happening at the present moment.

Comment: @userr2684291, I agree that tipically, *from the point of the storyteller, the time is the present*, but [More recently, analysts of its use in conversation have argued that it functions not by making an event present, but by marking segments of a narrative, foregrounding events (that is, signalling that one event is particularly important, relative to others) and marking a shift to évaluation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_present).

Comment: @LucianSava I don't see why these would be mutually exclusive. As CGEL puts it, "[historical present] can be regarded as a metaphorical use of the present tense, a device conventionally used [...] to make the narrative appear more vivid by **assimilating it to the here-and-now of the speech act**" (emphasis mine). Without being too formal about it, when I use this "device" (in my first language), I definitely think of these actions as occurring right now, sort of brought into and playing out at the present moment.

Comment: @userr2684291, Yes, they are not mutually exclusive. Both can be in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: @LucianSava To clarify: what's orthogonal, by my lights, are the method and the end result; the method being the (imagined, metaphorical, but nonetheless very "real-feeling" in the moment) present time which might be used to make the narrative more vivid or whatever. : )